# "Client Authentication failed" in paypal sandbox environment

Tags: javascript, node.js, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I downloaded the code from github and replaced the Client ID & App Secret. It works perfectly.
https://github.com/paypal-examples/docs-examples/tree/main/advanced-integration

But when I integrate codes to my project, it shows the error
{"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"Client Authentication failed"}

payment.html

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=Abcbu93zfm5Je0H7he6WL2FB4VqnH9SRSf5SvtDOYnJwFBwJl8M4umFYZVzpbW1oDH3AR9XsbtgRwTEl&currency=USD"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/css/cardfields.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="paypal-button-container" class="paypal-button-container"></div>
  <div class="card_container">
    <form id="card-form">
      ......
    </form>
  </div>

  <script src="../Javascript/payment.js"></script>
</body>
```

payment.js

```js
paypal.Buttons({
    createOrder: function() {
      return fetch("http://localhost:5555/api/orders", {
          method: "post",
          body: JSON.stringify({
            cart: [{
              sku: "<YOUR_PRODUCT_STOCK_KEEPING_UNIT>",
              quantity: "<YOUR_PRODUCT_QUANTITY>",
            }, ],
          }),
        })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((order) => order.id);
    },
    onApprove: function(data) {
      return fetch(`http://localhost:5555/api/orders/${data.orderID}/capture`, {
          method: "post",
        })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((orderData) => {
          // Successful capture! For dev/demo purposes:
          console.log(
            "Capture result",
            orderData,
            JSON.stringify(orderData, null, 2)
          );
          const transaction = orderData.purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0];
          alert(`Transaction ${transaction.status}: ${transaction.id}

            See console for all available details
          `);
        });
    },
  })
  .render("#paypal-button-container");
```

Backend: server.js

```js
const paypal = require("./paypal-api");
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const {port = 5555} = process.env;
const cors = require('cors');
require('dotenv').config();

app.use(cors());

//payment
app.get("/payment", async(req, res) => {
  const clientId = process.env.CLIENT_ID;
  try {
    const clientToken = await paypal.generateClientToken();
    res.render("checkout", {
      clientId,
      clientToken
    });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).send(err.message);
    console.log(err)
  }
});

// create order
app.post("/api/orders", async(req, res) => {
  try {
    const order = await paypal.createOrder();
    res.json(order);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).send(err.message);
  }
});

// capture payment
app.post("/api/orders/:orderID/capture", async(req, res) => {
  const {
    orderID
  } = req.params;
  try {
    const captureData = await paypal.capturePayment(orderID);
    res.json(captureData);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).send(err.message);
  }
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

paypal-api.js

```js
const fetch = (...args) =>
  import ('node-fetch').then(({
    default: fetch
  }) => fetch(...args));
const {CLIENT_ID,APP_SECRET} = process.env;
const base = "https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com";

// call the create order method
async function createOrder() {
  const purchaseAmount = "100.00"; // TODO: pull prices from a database
  const accessToken = await generateAccessToken();
  const url = `${base}/v2/checkout/orders`;
  const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: "post",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      intent: "CAPTURE",
      purchase_units: [{
        amount: {
          currency_code: "USD",
          value: purchaseAmount,
        },
      }, ],
    }),
  });

  return handleResponse(response);
}

// capture payment for an order
async function capturePayment(orderId) {
  const accessToken = await generateAccessToken();
  const url = `${base}/v2/checkout/orders/${orderId}/capture`;
  const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: "post",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
    },
  });

  return handleResponse(response);
}

// generate access token
async function generateAccessToken() {
  const auth = Buffer.from(CLIENT_ID + ":" + APP_SECRET).toString("base64");
  const response = await fetch(`${base}/v1/oauth2/token`, {
    method: "post",
    body: "grant_type=client_credentials",
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Basic ${auth}`,
    },
  });
  const jsonData = await handleResponse(response);
  return jsonData.access_token;
}

// generate client token
async function generateClientToken() {
  const accessToken = await generateAccessToken();
  const response = await fetch(`${base}/v1/identity/generate-token`, {
    method: "post",
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
      "Accept-Language": "en_US",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  });
  console.log('response', response.status)
  console.log('response', response)

  const jsonData = await handleResponse(response);
  return jsonData.client_token;
}

async function handleResponse(response) {
  if (response.status === 200 || response.status === 201) {
    return response.json();
  }

  const errorMessage = await response.text();
  throw new Error(errorMessage);
}

module.exports = {
  createOrder,
  capturePayment,
  generateAccessToken,
  generateClientToken
}
```

Comment: CLIENT_ID="Abcbu93zfm5Je0H7he6WL2FB4VqnH9SRSf5SvtDOYnJwFBwJl8M4umFYZVzpbW1oDH3AR9XsbtgRwTEl"

Comment: APP_SECRET="EJ7YXbDfp6k0nvqBDq-WBpTTdeciMjGGwOa7WEb7_IAM69SZutW0oBh_J0dKXwlewx9SPs_nEM77v_Ae"

Answer (score 0):

Where are the credentials stored in your project? Are you importing `dotenv` with it in the main app?

Did you create a `.env` file, save the credentials, and restart the server?

---

Other config schemes are of course possible, that's just what the example does, but based on the error it would seem the get auth token code doesn't have access to your credentials.

Comment: Yes, I stored the credentials in .env file. It works in the sample code but doesn't work in my code

Comment: Tried to `console.log(CLIENT_ID + ":" + APP_SECRET)` in the generateAccessToken function, returns "undefined". Guess that's the problem?

Comment: The first line of the example server.js is `import dotenv/config`. Are you doing that? If not you need some other way to get the config.

Comment: I used `require('dotenv').config()` instead. And I'm able to log the credentials in server.js `app.get("/payment"" ...)`. But getting "undefined" in "paypal-api.js"

Comment: Found the problem! Only added `require('dotenv').config()` in server.js but need to add this in paypal-api.js as well. Thank you!

Comment: Issue would seem to be the order in server.js, move it before your `require("./paypal-api");` Then the config import happens before the API file is loaded, and the API file does not need to load the config itself (comes from process.env)